# Expo Android APK Build Crashes with error TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_.default.createNode')

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

When I run the app on expo it runs perfectly fine, but as soon as I build it and try to run the app, I get the following error when the app instantly crashes:

```
 com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_.default.createNode'), stack:                                                                       
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

My code dependencies are :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
    "axios": "^1.3.0",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-location": "^15.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6",
    "json5": "^2.2.3",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.7"
  },
```

Why would the application work fine on expo but not work well on the APK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by updating the expo sdk to 48.0.0